# Prevent memory allocation in recursive combination generation

Tags: c++, recursion, graph-theory

(Sorry about the title, it's not the best descriptive)

I am playing with graph theory, and generating all possible combinations of a given set of input numbers.  Given the input set {2,3,4}, my possible combinations (of which there are `3!`), are:

[image: Tree]

The following recursive solution works, but I don't like the fact that I have to "copy" the input vector in order to "remove" the element that represents the node I am following in order to prevent including it for output again.  Elements I am going to output are stored in `vecValues` whereas the elements I can currently choose from are stored in `vecInput`:

```
void OutputCombos(vector<int>& vecInput, vector<int>& vecValues)
{
    // When hit 0 input size, output.
    if (vecInput.size() == 0)
    {
        for (int i : vecValues) cout << i << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    size_t nSize = vecInput.size();
    for (vector<int>::iterator iter = begin(vecInput); iter != end(vecInput); ++iter)
    {
        auto vecCopy = vecInput;
        vecCopy.erase(find(begin(vecCopy), end(vecCopy), *iter));
        vecValues.push_back(*iter);
        OutputCombos(vecCopy, vecValues);
        vecValues.pop_back();
    }
}

void OutputCombos(vector<int>& vecInput)
{
    vector<int> vecValues;
    OutputCombos(vecInput, vecValues);
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> vecInput{ 2,3,4 };
    OutputCombos(vecInput);
    return 0;
}
```

As expected from my state space tree, the output is

`2 3 4
2 4 3
3 2 4
3 4 2
4 2 3
4 3 2`

How can I get around this without having to make a copy of the vector for each recursive call please?

Comment: why aren't you creating the graph structures? With nodes and links?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation?

Comment: @bolov, all I am doing right now is outputting the combinations.  We could replace the adding of the "current" element with the creation of a tree node; however that would still not deal with the problem of having to copy the vector at each stage in order to remove an element...can you see how to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much studying I found inspiration in [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/travelling-salesman-problem-implementation-using-backtracking/) which gave me the ultimate solution.  The idea is that we keep a vector of `Boolean` values which indicates whether or not a particular value has been used in the combination; that way we don't need to remove the element that we have already used hence there is no memory allocation overhead.

So, when building the branch `{2,4,3}`, if we get to `{2,4}`, `vecTaken` will be `{true, false, true}` and `nNumBoolsSet` will be 2.  So when we loop, we will only "use" the element at index 1 of `vecInput` since that is the only element that has not been used as dictated by `vecTaken`.

```
void OutputCombos(vector<int>& vecInput, vector<int>& vecValues, vector<bool>& vecTaken, int& nNumBoolsSet)
{
    size_t nSize = vecInput.size();
    if (nNumBoolsSet == nSize)
    {
        for (int i : vecValues) cout << i << " ";
        cout << endl;
        return;
    }
    for (vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < nSize; ++i)
    {
        if (vecTaken[i] == false)
        {
            vecValues.push_back(vecInput[i]);
            vecTaken[i] = true;
            ++nNumBoolsSet;
            OutputCombos(vecInput, vecValues, vecTaken, nNumBoolsSet);
            vecTaken[i] = false;
            vecValues.pop_back();
            --nNumBoolsSet;
        }
    }
}

void OutputCombos(vector<int>& vecInput)
{
    vector<int> vecValues;
    vector<bool> vecTaken(vecInput.size(), false);
    int nNumBoolsSet = 0;
    OutputCombos(vecInput, vecValues, vecTaken, nNumBoolsSet);
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> vecInput{ 2,3,4 };
    OutputCombos(vecInput);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always just use `std::next_permutation` from `<algorithm>`

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> input {2, 3, 4};

  do {
        for (auto i : input) std::cout << i << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
     }  while(std::next_permutation(input.begin(), input.end()));

    return 0;
}
```

This gives you the same output. You might want to check out [a possible implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) of next_permutation, which involves swaps within the vector rather than copying the vector several times.

Comment: Thanks; I am aware of this function however its use doesn't fit with the nature of building of a graph.  Perhaps more elaboration is necessary to justify this.  I am looking at the travelling salesman problem.  A graph is built showing all possible routes; however if we store the "current" minimum, we can prevent further traversing of a certain path if we can see its distance will exceed the current minimum.  Generating all combinations in advance is therefore a waste.  This question was really just a dumbed down way of asking how to generate permutations...hope that clarifies...

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be closer to what you're looking for. A version without `std::next_permutation` that doesn't involve copying any vectors, and allows the input to remain `const`. However, it does this at the cost of checking the output in each iteration to make sure it doesn't add the same number twice.

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

template<typename T>
void OutputCombinations(
    const std::vector<T>& input,
    std::vector<typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator >& output)
{
  for(auto it = input.begin(); it != input.end(); ++it)
  {
    if (std::find(output.begin(), output.end(), it) == output.end())
    {
      output.push_back(it);
      if (output.size() == input.size())
      {
        for(auto node : output) std::cout << *node << " "; 
        std::cout << std::endl;
      }
      else OutputCombinations(input, output);

      output.pop_back();
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> nodes{ 2, 3, 4, 2 };
  std::vector<std::vector<int>::const_iterator> result{};
  OutputCombinations(nodes, result);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you have done there.  This is possibly faster than mine as well, since `find()` could have `O (log n)` complexity and my search through `vecTaken` could be `O(n)`.  A problem with this however would come if we have duplicate values in the input...in the case of the travelling salesman problem we can have duplicate values (distances).  But thanks for coming back to me anyway :)

Comment: Thanks for posting @Wad. It's a good problem to prompt thinking about algorithms.

Comment: @Wad I've changed it so it now handles duplicates

Comment: Ah I see what you've done; iterators are always going to be unique.  Nice!